# Open the doors to at for

Tags: word-usage

Are these phrases always used as fixed expressions? Would it be wrong to change them and say "open the doors at", "open the doors to", "open doors to", "open the door at", "open doors at", etc?

1. "Open doors at."
2. "Open the door to."
3. "Open doors for."
4. "Surrogacy opens the door for the exploitation of both the mother and the child."
5. "Surrogacy opens the door at the exploitation of both the mother and the child."
6. 'Surrogacy opens the door to the exploitation of both the mother and the child."
7. "Surrogacy opens doors for/at/to exploitation of both the mother and the child."
8. "Surrogacy opens the doors for/to/at the exploitation of both the mother and the child."

Comment: Open doors for guests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preposition ***at*** is *never* valid in the cited context. Both ***for*** and ***to*** are okay, but note that we *tend* to use ***to*** more often if what's now being "enabled" (by the metaphoric door being opened) is a ***process / activity*** of some kind...

[image] [<sup>(NGram link)</sup>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opened%20the%20door%20to%20competition%2Copened%20the%20door%20for%20competition&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

...whereas we tend to use ***for*** if the opportunity applies to ***actual agents*** now able to do something...

[image]
[<sup>(NGram link)</sup>](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=opened%20the%20door%20to%20competitors%2Copened%20the%20door%20for%20competitors&year_start=1940&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10)

But it's important to note that this is only a *tendency*. Nobody would notice anything remotely unusual if you always used *either* preposition in every case.

Also note that plural ***open doors to/for competition/competitors*** isn't often used for the more general metaphoric sense - but it *does* occur where the progress of an *individual* in a particular field of endeavour is being facilitated in several ways: *John's uncle opened doors for him to work in the Diplomatic Service*.

Comment: I don't think numbers matter much. More important is to see actual examples....

Answer (score 2):

1. "Open (the) doors at." is incorrect unless you are talking about a time and a literal door. e.g. "I open the doors at 10 O'clock. Or a location and literal door: e.g. "I open the door at the end of the corridor" Do not use this for your example.
2. "Open the door to." - For your example sentence this is the correct choice. It is used in a methaphorical sense to mean "to allow something new to start": https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/open-the-door-to-sth

"'Surrogacy opens the door to the exploitation of both the mother and the child." is correct. The other options for this sentence are incorrect.

3. "Open doors for." This is used for the creation of opportunity and is usually used when talking about the options someone has in life from a networking point of view. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/open-doors

This is the only option where door should be pluralised to doors unless you are talking about literal doors.

When used in your example sentence #7 it sort of personifies the exploitation and suggests you want to provide it with opportunities which doesn't make sense. It is likely that the sentence would be understood but you should use option #6 in this case.

Be careful with "Open **the** doors for" - This should only be used when you are literally opening a door so that someone else may use it.

Comment: One minor correction: **at** could also be correct if we're talking about location, e.g. "Open the doors at the north end of the hall."